# Measure Interaction to Next Paint (INP) with automated clicking on all elements

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, seo, core-web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint

I prepared a javascript code which you can run in Chrome Console. It clicks on all elements on page which are  links or buttons.

Then it outputs a table with CSS classes of those elements and a time it took for a website to resnpond to user click.

**THE PROBLEM**
While clicking on links and buttons, eventually script clicks on an element that contains link to other pages, causing page to refresh and erase my data.

How can I prevent this script from opening any kind of links and causing page to refresh? I tried excluding href and src attributes, but still there were some websites for which it didn't work.

**EXAMPLES**
It works here and doesn't open any links:
https://www.theguardian.com/football/2024/jan/08/how-the-guardian-ranked-the-100-best-female-footballers-in-the-world-2023

It doesn't work here and always open links:
https://www.upwork.com/hire/python-developers/

**The script:**

```
async function measureINP() {
const results = [];
const processedElements = new Set();

function simulateClick(element) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        function interactionHandler(event) {
            // Prevent default action to keep the page stable
            event.preventDefault();
            const startTime = performance.now();

            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                const endTime = performance.now();
                const inp = endTime - startTime;
                element.removeEventListener('click', interactionHandler);
                resolve({ element: element, inp: inp });
            });
        }

        // Add a timeout to reject the promise if no response in 5 seconds
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            element.removeEventListener('click', interactionHandler);
            reject(new Error(`Timeout waiting for response from ${element.tagName}`));
        }, 5000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            element.addEventListener('click', interactionHandler);
            element.click();
        }, 100); // Wait for 100ms before triggering the click event

        // Clean up the timeout when the interaction handler is called
        element.addEventListener('click', () => clearTimeout(timeoutId), { once: true });
    });
}

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('a, button, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], .menu-button');
for (const element of elements) {
    const elementIdentifier = `${element.tagName}${element.id ? '#' + element.id : ''}${element.className ? '.' + element.className.replace(/\s+/g, '.') : ''}`;

    // Define a list of keywords and attributes that commonly indicate language-changing buttons
    const languageKeywords = ['language', 'lang', 'translate'];
    const languageAttributes = ['data-lang', 'data-translate'];

    // Check if the element matches any of the language indicators
    const elementTextContent = element.textContent.toLowerCase();
    const elementAttributes = Array.from(element.attributes).map(attr => attr.name.toLowerCase());
    const isLanguageButton =
        languageKeywords.some(keyword => elementTextContent.includes(keyword)) ||
        languageAttributes.some(attribute => elementAttributes.includes(attribute));

    // Check if the element is a language-changing button
    if (isLanguageButton) {
        console.log(`Skipping language-changing button: ${elementIdentifier}`);
        continue;
    }

    // Skip if this element has already been processed
    if (processedElements.has(elementIdentifier)) {
        continue;
    }

    try {
        const data = await simulateClick(element);
        processedElements.add(elementIdentifier); // Add to the set after processing
        results.push({
            element: elementIdentifier,
            interaction: 'Click',
            "INP (milliseconds)": Number(data.inp.toFixed(2)) // Rename key to "INP (milliseconds)"
        });
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); // Wait for 100ms before the next interaction
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error with element ${element.tagName}:`, error);
    }
}

console.table(results); } measureINP();
```

Comment: You could try the Navigation API (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/navigation-api) which allows you to intercept navigations. Note this is Chromium-only.